# When to use hyphenated "TagA-TagB" instead of searching [TagA] AND [TagB]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking to find questions related specifically to JavaScript's canvas.  I noticed that one single question had been tagged `javascript-canvas` while the others had separate (`javascript` `canvas`) or (`java` `canvas`) tags.

Since I can now re-tag questions I eliminated the outlier.  But then I noticed `javascript-events`, `javascript-functions`, `javascript-editor`, etc.

Offhand I would say that "Related Tags" seems to be the right way to tackle this.  For instance, there are 442 tags for "javascript-events" but if it were just "events" it would still show up in the list you get after clicking javascript.

Admittedly `javascript-functions` would not show up, but who's to say it is more deserving of a special tag than `javascript-jquery` or `javascript-google-maps`?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Meta isn't just for questions but discussions as well as the discussion tag would show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are a lot of cases where the `technology-feature` style is more appropriate than the `technology feature` style. Keeping the tags separate will make searching and favoriting easier and more effective. Hyphenated tags are really meant for use in place of spaces, like `visual-studio`.

Answer (score 3):

Each tag for your question should stand by itself.  So `visual` and `studio` are bad tags because one doesn't make sense without the other.  `javascript` and `canvas` are both independent as well.  However, sometimes you also need to clarify a tag.  For example, several different programming environments provide a canvas; which one are you talking about?  In this case, searching for `javascript` *and* `canvas` should cover you, but there are cases where that doesn't hold.