# What did happen with "xpathengines" and "xqueryengines" tags, and why?

Tags: support, tags

> ***About the bounty***: Up today the original question is not fully
> answered. I'm asking for the actual
> reasons of the merge. *I've also deleted my own comments so question and answers can stand one in front of the others instead of... feelings.*

---

[xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines) was a tag used by the community but now it's gone. I don't see any discussion about this... deprecation. [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/99534/) (Good 'til the next data dump)

**Edit**: The same holds for [xqueryengines](/questions/tagged/xqueryengines). [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/99535/) (Good 'til the next data dump)

**Edit 2**: From @ChrisF's comment and Rebecca Chernoff' brief answer, it's confirmed that this was an action taken by a moderator. I don't agree with it, but I might be wrong. I can't decide without an explanation. **I think the reason is part of what happen.** But again, I can't make an informed [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) without an explanation (Do note that this affects **230 questions**).

**Edit 3**: Because anyone letting himself by comments instead of answers might wander why it's important the actual reason for ***this*** merge (as been part of the question) against general answers about merging or opinions not analyzing ***these*** questions in particular and how they meet some establish criteria ("citation needed") resulting in damage for both askers and answerers, here are some numbers ("Do measure by the same yardstick!"):

There are at least five tags related to Javascript. These are the numbers of the questions tagged with those and without [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

[javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events): **620** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events+-javascript

[javascript-framework](/questions/tagged/javascript-framework): **75** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-framework+-javascript

[unobtrusive-javascript](/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-javascript): **99** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-javascript+-javascript

[javascript-performance](/questions/tagged/javascript-performance): **4** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-performance+-javascript

[serverside-javascript](/questions/tagged/serverside-javascript): **32** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverside-javascript+-javascript

Comment: Do you have any examples of questions that were tagged with that tag so we can look through the revision history?

Comment: Google cache: [The *xpathengines* tag page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:w-2Onmg_0jwJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpathengines+site:stackoverflow.com+xpathengines). The revision histories of the posts don't contain any hint on the removal of the tag, but it seems to have been renamed to *xpath*.

Comment: Looks like it was renamed in the database by a dev. I don't know why a synonym wasn't set up (which would have been the way I would have done it).

Comment: I could have sworn there was another MSO question about this, but it's not coming up in search, or even the deleted questions list.

Comment: Sorry, @Chris seems to know more than I do.

Comment: There is by the way already a synonym on xpath tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/synonyms, but it has 0 votes. I can't upvote it and I assume **a lot** of people also not. Anyway, the tag synonym approach has to be revised as it gets too little attention.

Comment: @Alejandro: I have expressed my position on this important problem in a separate answer.

Comment: @Alejandro Sorry for the confusion, I appear to be misinterpreting some of your comments, and confusing them with comments Dimitre has made.

Comment: @mmyers: Exactly. Or, as I said in another comment, they behave like an elephant in a china shop.

Comment: @mmyers Here's [a dramatized version of this question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUt87BGKMaY).  You are played by Harrison Ford (you handsome devil!) as one of the few that somehow managed to outrun the train.

Comment: @Adam: That's actually the scene I was thinking of. (I'm glad to see my character has moved up to A-list actors since the Stack Overflow movie last fall.)

Comment: @mmyers You were always on my a-list. [Am I being too intence?](http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/gs52v/what_not_to_do/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem)

Comment: @Alejandro, you **should not** have deleted your comments, as they helped firmly establish your justification for having the tags.

Comment: @Charles: Comments have never been such important. If so, then they should be an answer. I did post my own answer not to this question (I'm afraid of) but to yours questions. In other hand, comments are **hiding** the answers, or the lack of it.

Comment: @Alejandro, good eyes on those other tags.  However, in this case, it looks like *most* of the questions in every one of those tags *are* also tagged with `javascript`.  The questions in those tags that are missing `javascript` should have it *added*.  This is a *distinct* situation from the `-engines` tags, in which questions existed only *without* the parent `xpath` or `xquery` tag.  If those JS tags stood alone more often than not, I'd say that they deserved a merge.  But that is clearly not the case, and I'm not sure that raising this point is going to be useful to this topic.

Comment: @Charles: Your wrote _"`javascript` should have it added"_ **The fact is that user don't seems to needed**. _"This is a distinct situation from the `-engines` tags"_ **You have to probe it and not to enunciate it**. You seems biased. Don't dance around arguments in your comments. Add your answer instead.

Comment: @Alejandro, I will not add an answer for two reasons.  First, others have said what I'd say with far more grace -- I've upvoted instead.  Second, my answer would not be eligible for the bounty because I am not a moderator and can not answer your bounty-specific question to your satisfaction.

Comment: Further, Shog9 has explained the situation with the `javascript-` prefix tags.  Further further, [the `-engines` tags sound like this description of "meta" tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which are "**discouraged**".

Comment: @Charles: _"The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question"_ `xpathengines` describe precisely the content of those questions. Stop dancing...

Comment: @Alejandro, except that it **doesn't** precisely describe the content of those questions **as a group**.  The questions have *nothing* to do with **each other** in the slightest, and that makes it a *horrible* tag.

Comment: @shog9, @Rebecca Chernoff and all SO Managment: "Congratulations"! @Alejandro has cancelled his account at SO. He was one of the best specialists in XSLT, XPath and XML. `You have successfully eliminated one of your leading specialists` !

Comment: @Dimitre: every time I get dragged back to this question, I have to page past five of your deleted "answers" and dozens of inflammatory comments. If you actually care about this site, its users, or at least the little bit of respect you've managed to accumulate within your area of expertise, you'd do well to take a long, hard look at the way you've behaved here and how it reflects on them. I know you don't buy it, but... I don't have a dog in this fight. See ya in the funny pages...

Answer (score 12):

My understanding is as follows:

xpath and xquery are essentially languages for dealing with XML data, such as HTML.

The generic terms "xpath engines" and "xquery engines" refer to the fact that there are many, many implementations of xpath and xquery.

It would be akin to marking C and C++ questions [ccompilers](/questions/tagged/ccompilers) and [c++compilers](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bcompilers).  If the question is about

- The compiler itself (ie, NOT a question about the language)
- Multiple compilers (ie, NOT a question about how one compiler implements it)

then it would be reasonable to use those tags.

There are precious few questions that need to be marked as such - those questions which really concern a number of engines, perhaps, but most of those questions really only need to discuss the one engine that the OP is using, and so having a tag for that specific engine might be useful.

Looking at the google cache, though, I can plainly see that most of those questions are not about the multitude of xpathengines, and that the tag is superfluous for them.

There may be questions that would fit that tag, however the practical reality is that the tag is being egregiously abused by those who don't know that their question has no need for it.  It's apparent that a lot of users are adding it because they don't know what else to add.

Tags are meant to make it *easy to search* for specific types of questions.  It's quite obvious that these tags were useless - they didn't make it easier to find true engine questions.  When people search Google for "xpathengines" the search results would be littered with BAD matches from stackoverflow, which lowers the page ranking of the site as a whole, and the questions individually.

Since people are using them incorrectly, and they have a negative impact on on site searches ans well as off site searches, then it's reasonable to ban them, even if there are some valid uses for them.  The bad, unfortunately, outweighs the good.

Comment: @Dimitre Then please explain it to me.  Your answer doesn't give us enough information to understand why it's important that the question "How to find child elements of a specific node with tinypath" requires the xpathengines tag.  You are the expert, you should be able to help us understand why those tags are necessary, and when they should be used.  So far your answer lacks this basic information, and so you're forcing us to simply accept your word, or worse - search google and try to make sense of it ourselves.  Educate us.

Comment: @Alejandro *"What did happen with “xpathengines” and “xqueryengines” tags, and why?"* suggests that you are interested in what happened to them and why.  Perhaps if you reviewed your question and edited the title and the body, then you might get the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @Alejandro So If I have a question about what arguments are valid for a particular compiler's implementation of a given method, then I should be including the `c-compiler` tag along with, say, the `gcc` tag?  I don't understand - what value is added to the question by adding the generic term for all xpath engines when the question is clearly about one particular xpath engine?  Either I don't understand the situation clearly enough (so educate me!) or you and Dimitre don't understand the purpose of tags.

Comment: @Alejando They were removed by a moderator.  It is because they were believed to be redundant.

Comment: @Dimitre @Alejandro Why are you two refusing to educate us?  Are you claiming that we are of such low intelligence that attempting to do so would be a waste of your precious time?  You've already implied that people who don't understand should keep their nose out of your business.  Well, my nose is in your business.  You can either educate it, or suffer the consequences of an uneducated audience moderating your contributions.  It's your choice, but I don't understand why you insist on keeping us in the dark.

Comment: @Adam Davis: There are good books on both subjects. Hope this link may help (at least for XPAth): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @Dimitre Thanks for the link.  I've added two of them to my reading list and will reassess whether to change my behavior as soon as I understand the difference.  Until then, or until someone explains it in a paragraph or two, I'm afraid I'm going to have to concur with the moderator who first made the change.

Comment: @Dimitre It would be very nice if we could sort this out right now, but making a decision without understanding the situation would be worse than waiting until we understood it.  However, for your general question about how we should approach tag changes in the future, check out [Should experts be consulted prior to tag changes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89877/should-experts-be-consulted-prior-to-tag-changes) and add your thoughts.

Comment: @Dimitre I am not part of SO administration in any capacity, and am a user of these sites just like you.  Please don't let my poor behavior or choices reflect badly on SO or its administration.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Shog9 had nothing to do with these tags outside of responding in this discussion after the merge had been done.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, the who is not important.  The fact that neither you nor Alejandro are answering the important questions, such as Charles' comment on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why/89904#89904) is very telling.

Answer (score 8):

These tags were merged by a moderator.

Basic details about tag merges:  tag merges are done when the tags have similar meanings, are splitting questions that can be grouped, make it more difficult for users to find questions, etc.  Tag merging also increases visibility of questions since users set up filters.  (these have been mentioned several times in the comments, but adding them here since the comments are a disaster).

Comment: Thanks. But this is a little bit... brief answer. Might we know the reason? I know that this was retagged as `support` but I'd tagged first as `discussion`, also. Should I also tag this as `request` for undo?

Comment: @Alejandro, I don't know anything other than what I posted.

Comment: @Alejandro, um, what?

Comment: @Alejandro: Do you mean the questions disappeared?

Comment: @Alejandro, that *might* have been me.  The tag showed up in the "list of new tags" on the 10k review list. I couldn't tell how the question was about xpath engines *in general*, so I untagged the question. This was before I saw the drama here on Meta and realized what I'd be stepping in, of course. If I'd known that there was controversy about the tag, I'd have left them alone until there was consensus.  [This is the question I edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866024).  I have not reverted my edit -- for now.  I suggest that the change remains until there's a clear forward path.

Comment: @Alejandro, if you want anyone to be able to get behind your crusade here, perhaps explaining *why* that question is tagged incorrectly would help.

Comment: @Alejandro, looking at the merge can be handled after someone explains *why* it was bad.  These rants by you and Dimitre are not helping.  I suggest creating another question, do not make that question a rant, and clearly explain why these tags are not the same.  You can use the question Charles pointed to for explaining.

Comment: @Alejandro, the tags were merged.  Done deal.  You can choose to harp over that, or you can be productive and answer the questions asked in this discussion about why [xpath] and [xquery] are not suitable, particularly Charles' comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why/89904#89904).  "Against what can I argue?" is the wrong approach.  Don't argue.  Calmly answer and explain.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, the tags were merged because they are similar enough to go under the same grouping.  This has been said many, many, many times throughout this thread.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff: Nobody ever answered the question why the users of the tags were completely ignored and their opinion was never asked and taken into account. Due to actions like this I don't trust SO's administration about anything they say -- just look what they are doing. The users have only theoretical rights to create new tags and to tag questions into these. Regardless how much effort was put by the tagging users (badges they had been "rewarded" for this) SO abruptly destroys this enormous work. Go tagging after that. The tag structure will soon be flat as the brains who did this.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff: SO's administration are not a specialists in this area to decide what is similar and what degree of similarity is needed in order to justify a decision to merge such tags. This has been said, to quote you, "many, many, many times throughout this thread". SO administration's decision reflects and promotes ignorance -- go on like this and mess up every single tag to show to users who and what SO administration is. Go on like this to show every user how much SO "cares" about them.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff: This is an excellent example showing how a company should *not* treat its users -- I will take my time to describe in my blog how this company treats its users.

Comment: @Dimitre: the idea that you can show up and claim "I am a specialist, you must listen to me" or "I have rep, you must listen to me" is antithetical to *the fundamental philosophy of SO*: Any given user can answer well or poorly on any given question, and you don't start out with +10 on your answer just because you answered well somewhere else. Allowing one user to abuse others simply because he feels he "owns" a given tag and can therefore dictate who uses it is beyond absurd, and your raging assertion that it *should be* is comical. Might I recommend a nice cup of tea?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, it has been answered, over and over.  Tags exist things to group questions so users can find questions they are interested in easily.  Thus, merges are done when tags are separated out making it difficult for users to find questions.  We don't collude against our users.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89877/should-experts-be-consulted-prior-to-tag-changes - you've been asked to contribute to that constructively, but you haven't.  If you feel strongly about this issue, *which you seem to*, this is a chance to help change things.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, I agree with everything in your last comment.  Both users and team members have tried to work with you and Alejandro.  I'm sorry we are unable to resolve things.

Answer (score 7):

### The rationale for the merge

The [xpath-engines] tag was merged into [xpath] because it was creating a distinction that non-expert users could neither understand nor properly use.

There are *other* problems with such tags as well; these have been discussed to the point of exhaustion in other answers here. In particular, [see Adam's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why/89839#89839):

> Tags are meant to make it easy to search for specific types of questions. It's quite obvious that these tags were useless - they didn't make it easier to find true engine questions. When people search Google for "xpathengines" the search results would be littered with BAD matches from stackoverflow, which lowers the page ranking of the site as a whole, and the questions individually.

Further references (read *all* answers and discussion):

- [When to use hyphenated "TagA-TagB" instead of searching [TagA] AND [TagB]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/when-to-use-hyphenated-taga-tagb-instead-of-searching-taga-and-tagb)
- [Congratulations Eric Lippert for finally winning the 'c#-language' badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/congratulations-eric-lippert-for-finally-winning-the-c-language-badge)
- [A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)

---

### Appealing to tradition w/ JavaScript

Regarding your last edit:

[javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) is... [annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33023/on-the-tagging-of-events-and-event-handling/). Strictly-speaking, it should be [dom-events](/questions/tagged/dom-events), which in turn should be [dom+events](/questions/tagged/dom%2bevents) (that is, *two* tags) - but because there's this persistent (and... totally understandable) belief that some form of browser DOM is actually *part of the JavaScript language*, it's not. This tag originated very early on in the life of the site, and has proved itself extremely popular... Indeed, it is perhaps the single best example of why this sort of [hyphenated subgrouping is a bad idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/when-to-use-hyphenated-taga-tagb-instead-of-searching-taga-and-tagb): many, if not *most* of [those 600+ questions you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events+-javascript) *are* JavaScript questions, but they won't show up on anyone's feed unless they've thought to use wildcards.

Same goes for the rest, *with the exception of [unobtrusive-javascript](/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-javascript)*, which is [the proper name for a specific *technique*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript) (and not a language or language subset). Actually, [serverside-javascript](/questions/tagged/serverside-javascript) *might* [fall into this category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) as well, but I'm skeptical: those questions would be better off tagged as [javascript] + *server-side engine*.

#### So how does this apply to [xpath-*]?

Well, it's a poor analog... The biggest problem with retagging most of these - especially javascript-events - is that they imply *two* tags: so you can't just merge them and be done; those 600+ questions without the primary tag would still have to be re-tagged manually, a non-trivial effort.

But it does illustrate something very important: this is the kind of mess that can result if namespaced-tagging is left unchecked. Merging the 200-odd [xpath-engines] questions was probably an easy decision, since the collateral damage was effectively non-existent (I've seen all of *two* questions so far that shouldn't have been tagged [xpath] as a result); merging [javascript-events] would immediately guarantee *hundreds* of mis-tagged questions. **You don't want to wait until there are 2K+ instances of a tag to clean up the mess** - it's much more likely to *not get done*.

### But I don't want to see questions which aren't Pure XPath™!

If the idea of dealing with messy platform-specific details fills you with dread, simply exclude the platform: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath+-java+-c#+-php+-javascript

The system provides numerous tools for highlighting and filtering questions. If the results aren't to your liking, consider that *adding tags that describe the platform* is preferable to removing information that others depend on.

Comment: @Shog9: You wrote: _"Well, it's a poor analog"_ Sorry, my bad. But this clearly shows two standards. And that is the reason for asking about *this specific merge of `xpath-engine` with `xpath`*. **After 12 days there is no answer about this**: you are talking about your opinion of `javascript-*` and @Rebecca Chernoff wrote that she doesn't know anything other than what she posted: it seems that no moderator could neither ask to the responsible nor answer on his behalf.

Comment: @Alejandro: there are *waaay* more than two standards... That's why this Meta site has been host to *thousands* of discussions on the various aspects of this, and why there are plenty of tags that violate current standards (btw: look up "appeal to tradition"). But **yes, your question has been answered.** *Repeatedly.* According to the person involved, Adam nailed it in his answer right off the bat, so you're probably not going to get yet *another* answer, since frankly we've all spent a little bit too much time dealing with this and still have to go deal with Dimitre throwing a tantrum on SO.

Comment: @Shog9: @Adam Davis' answers says that _"it would be reasonable to use those tags"_ *but* _"the bad, unfortunately, outweighs the good"_. I've showed you that this is not the case for `xpathengines` with concrete examples. About my question of the reason of the person involved: if you are not such person (as you have denied this consistently) but you know through confidence that any of the shared opinions was his reason for this merge, you could add that to your answer and I would consider this question answered.

Comment: @Alejandro: done.

Comment: @Shog9: Ok, I will award the bounty to you, but where is the link to the "non-expert users could neither understand or use" policy?

Comment: @Alejandro: not sure there's any specific policy statement there, but... You can consider this question a definition of policy if you want. For future reference, if you plan to start re-tagging questions on an existing subject with a brand-new tag, post a question here on Meta and try to get at least some consensus. Doubly so if you plan to *remove* a broad, well-known tag. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Answer (score 2):

*Suddenly I got a bump on the head. I said to me: "Apparently I did something wrong". Then I asked those around me: "What did I do wrong?". And they answered: "Someone gave you a bump on the head. **Explain yourself!**"*

Let's see the first five questions in the query that @Shog9 kindly made for us:

- [Cross-browser XPath implementation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183369/cross-browser-xpath-implementation-in-javascript):

  > I'm looking for a XPath library to query over XML documents in FF, IE, Opera and Safari... and couldn't find one. Have you seen any?
- [Build XML using XPATH - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184632/build-xml-using-xpath-c):

  > Hi Guys, I saw this post does anyone knows about some C# framework doing similar like dom4j do? I need to build up XMLs using XPATHs.
- [XPath syntax within binding XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638247/xpath-syntax-within-binding-xaml)

  > What is the syntax for using XPath with Binding in XAML? Are there any MSDN pages which describe where to put the braces?
- [How do you use the --pattern option of xmllint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224613/how-do-you-use-the-pattern-option-of-xmllint)

  > I'm trying to see how libxml implements XPath support, so it made sense to me to test using xmllint. *[...]* **What is xmllint's --pattern option for, and how does it work?**
- [Using ms: xpath functions inside XPathExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320505/using-ms-xpath-functions-inside-xpathexpression):

  > I am trying to use Microsoft XPath Extension Functions (such as [ms:string-compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256114.aspx)) inside an XPathExpression object. *[...]* Is there any way to do this (or any other way to use ms: extensions inside an XPathExpression)?

From https://stackoverflow.com/tags

> A tag is a keyword or label that
>   categorizes your question with other,
>   similar questions. Using the right
>   tags makes it easier for others to
>   find and answer your question.

From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info

[image]

**Do note**:

- None of the questions ask for an
  XPath expression.
- None of the answers contains an XPath
  expression (other than a "place
  holder")
- All the questions have referenced either the host language or the environment where an XPath engine implementation must be aviable.
- Most of the answers are code of the host language.
- None of the answers reference themself with the XPath specs.
- Most of the links point to specific XPath engines implementations' documentation

---

***UPDATE:***

From @Charles' [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why#comment-223881):

> Is there ever a case where a question
>   would be tagged with x.+engine where
>   it *wouldn't* **be tagged with
>   xpath/xquery**?

Let's see the next five question on the SEDE query:

- [Performing complicated XPath queries in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056337/performing-complicated-xpath-queries-in-scala):

  > What's the simplest API to use in scala to perform the following XPath queries on a document? *[...some legal XPath expression...]* (`s` is defined as a nickname for a particular namespace)

  *Most upvoted answer:*

  > Well, I don't understand the `s:` notation, and couldn't find it on XPath spec either. However, ignoring that this would look like this: *[... Scala code workaround...]* I can't answer about namespaces, though. No clue how to work with them on searches, if it's even possible. The docs mention `@{uri}attribute` for prefixed attributes, not does not mention anything about prefixed elements.

  **Do note:** We went from a perfectly legal XPath expression to a Scala code workaround.
- [Glassfish v3 and XPath.compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153748/glassfish-v3-and-xpath-compile-error):

  > We are migrating fairly new web application from tomcat to glassfish and everything is working well except for some xpath code that is used to parse some xml returned from a third party service. *[...]* Here is a snippet that throws an null pointer exception: *[...one method from an XPath engine API...]* If this change is made in the code: *[...other method from another XPath engine API...]*

  *Falls in the same category than first five*
- [XPath loop with Selenium and perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210255/xpath-loop-with-selenium-and-perl):

  > I'm trying to extract all name values in input fields using selenium and perl. *[...]* This xpath works in finding all relevant matches: *[...valid XPath expression...]* However, how to extract the value of the @name attribute for each individual matches? I understand the principle is to construct a loop: *[...code...]*

  *Most upvoted answer*: a code workaround...

  > Replace `1` with your counter. *[...]*

  **Do note**: @Dimitre's answer (a correct XPath expression) is downvoted. *We might think that something XPath language can do, in fact it can't.*
- [XPath must be a literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213723/xpath-must-be-a-literal)

  > I have a stored proc with a parameter which I want to have contain an XPath expression which can then be used to retrieve a value in a select, but the r.value(...) exception message says that I can only use literals.

  *Falls in the same category than first five*
- [Sitecore query does not support count() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251985/sitecore-query-does-not-support-count-function)

  > Sitecore query is based on XPATH, but looks like it does not support count() function. My query is this: *[...something that is not standard XPath...]*

  *Accepted answer:*

  > Try this: *[...other thing that is not standard XPath...]*

  **Do note:** This is not XPath. I won't help others looking for an XPath answer to their questions.

---

Because the only answer wich is claiming to be the actual answer to this question is @Shog9's one:

> @Shog9: [...]. About my question of
>   the reason of the person involved: if
>   you are not such person (as you have
>   denied this consistently) but you know
>   through confidence that any of the
>   shared opinions was his reason for
>   this merge, you could add that to your
>   answer and I would consider this
>   question answered. –
>   [`Alejandro`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why/#comment-225449)
>
> @Alejandro: done. –
>   [`Shog9`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why/#comment-225459)

We should discuss it.

> ### The rationale for the merge
>
> The [xpath-engines] tag was merged
>   into [xpath] because it was creating a
>   distinction that non-expert users
>   could neither understand nor properly
>   use.

Saddly, there is no reference for this other than a circular definition:

> @Alejandro: not sure there's any
>   specific policy statement there,
>   but... You can consider this question
>   a definition of policy if you want.
>   [...] - `Shog9`

But let see the most relevant links provided by @Shog9 for "further references":

#### [Congratulations Eric Lippert for finally winning the c#-language badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/congratulations-eric-lippert-for-finally-winning-the-c-language-badge/62670#62670)

> IMHO, [c#-language] doesn't appear to
>   signify anything that [c#] doesn't
>   already indicate.

This is not the case for [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines) because the further begins where the former specification ends (see my epilogue).

> I certainly don't see anything common
>   to the questions currently tagged that
>   would appear to require a separate tag

I've already present six common properties of the questions with [xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines), all of them about the content of the questions and the prerequisites in order to answer (enviroment, host language against just an input sample and a clear determination of the parts of the XML instance that OP wants to address for [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and its synonym [xpath-expression](/questions/tagged/xpath-expression)). But, wait! ...

> indeed, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308432/do-try-catch-blocks-hurt-performance-when-exceptions-are-not-thrown) would appear to require the consideration of a
>   specific implementation...
>
> That said, there is a [ecma262] tag
>   for questions on the ECMAScript
>   standard itself or questions on its
>   implementation that are potentially
>   orthogonal to JavaScript use or any
>   specific implementation of it.

So, there are tags that deals *"with messy platform-specific details"*. And getting better:

> So I could see a similar tag
>   ([c#-specification] or [ecma334]
>   say...) used for questions on the C#
>   standard that aren't directly
>   concerned with the use of language or
>   its common implementations.

Wich is exactly the case for [xpathengine](/questions/tagged/xpathengine).

> Assuming there are actually questions that
>   would benefit from such a thing...

So, we end again with the benefits measure: as I proof there will be some damage for people trying to learn XPath if we expose them to answers dealing with non-standard complain implementations.

---

### Epilogue:

Is this distinction between [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines) some invention? From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-implementation-defined

> Certain aspects of language processing
>   are described in this specification as
>   **implementation-defined** or **implementation-dependent**.
>
> - [Definition: **Implementation-defined** indicates an aspect that may differ between
>     implementations, but must be specified
>     by the implementor for each particular
>     implementation.]
> - [Definition: **Implementation-dependent** indicates an aspect that may differ between
>     implementations, is not specified by
>     this or any W3C specification, and is
>     not required to be specified by the
>     implementor for any particular
>     implementation.]
>
> A language aspect described in this
>   specification as
>   **implementation-defined** or **implementation dependent** may be further constrained by the
>   specifications of a host language in
>   which XPath is embedded.

- Determining the boundaries of a problem is a key for its resolution. The XPath specifications define the XPath language scope and also is telling us what is out of its scope, what belongs to the XPath implementations scope. As such, the standard API for XPath engines invocation is part of DOM specification in http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/ instead of the XPath specification.
- [xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines) it's not a meta tag: it reference the content of the question.
- [xpathengines](/questions/tagged/xpathengines) fully categorize those questions together: from the point of view of XPath specification (authority) the only proper answer is "that's implementation defined/dependent". In order to be answered the prerequisites are the XPath implementation reference, the host language and somes time the environment when the former is unknown. Those are not the prerequisites for an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) question.
- Does it worth it? For sure it would hurt people trying to learn XPath. **And we are all here to learn**.

Comment: Wait - *you* tagged all those questions. Does *anyone asking questions* even understand how/when it's supposed to be used?

Comment: Actually our answer was: "You got bumped on the head because you went through a passage we thought no one used, and there are low beams in that path.  If you give us a good reason why people should be able to use that path safely without getting bumped, we'll make it safe, otherwise we suggest you use a different path"

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason the [xpath] tag is only for questions asking for an XPath expression.  A question about an XPath engine *is still a question about XPath* isn't it?

Comment: @Shog9 Actually he indicated in a comment to my answer that he didn't tag those questions, *"...Also do note that this change is making wrong attributions: I did not tag questions with xpath in pleaces it says I did. – Alejandro 4 hours ago"*  which is rather interesting.

Comment: +1 for the research, though it's not compelling enough to change my opinion.  Quite the opposite: the last three linked questions are all about *specific engine implementations*! I'd argue that if you want to classify engine-specific behavior, that *engine* should have it's own tag. Adding a "this question is about how to use an engine" tag doesn't *seem* to add a lot of categorical value, from my point of view. Can you explain what categorical value having the tag adds *for users* when using the site? (edit: wow, I took 12 minutes to write that?)

Comment: @Alejandro: As far as examples go, those questions don't *look* very related (apart from having a connection to XML/XPath). And the rather meta relation of you adding the xpathengines tag to them. I guess I'm saying, if you tagged five questions and 200+ other users took and ran with it, great; if you tagged 230 questions, um, that doesn't help your cause... And if it's somewhere in between, [more data needed]. At this point, I *strongly suspect* both you and Dimitre are missing the point made on another question, that a tag *understood only by a handful of experts in another tag* isn't usable

Comment: @Alejandro: regarding your original question: did you or Dimitre engage in any discussion before adding that tag to scores of questions? If so, pointing to it could help *this* discussion considerably.

Comment: Ahhh... I do recall that room being rather busy during the beta; surprised it didn't continue. @Alejandro

Comment: I read through the chat transcript of the room from the beta chat - I didn't see a discussion on [xpathengines] and [xqueryengines].

Comment: Okay, let me find another way to ask the same question.  Is there ever a case where a question would be tagged with x.+engine where it *wouldn't* be tagged with xpath/xquery? If so, why not, and can you give **clear examples of questions that would fall under both, either, or just one of the set**? They don't have to be links to existing questions, make them up to demonstrate the categorization differences. I think that would help clarify the discussion greatly.

Comment: @shog9: You are *Lying* about the xslt-xsltprocessor merge. Then I and a number of other tag leaders explained why we needed these tags *not* merged. I still keeps the emails. Except for being the elephant in a china shop you need to refresh your failing memory. Why don't you deal with things you understand well and leave all other things to other people? Until now I had high respect for SO, now because of you I no longer believe SO is a good Q/A site. It is a china shop ruled by elephants.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, I'm not saying that xpath expressions and xpath engines are the same.  I'm saying they both deal with xpath in some way.  Dogs and cats are both animals.  Speaking of not wanting to waste your time, an answer to Charles is still noticeably absent.

Comment: @Dimitre: [I don't trust my memory on such matters, when I can simply open your profile.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52735/should-the-xslt-and-xsl-tags-be-merged/63601#63601) (and for the record: [my tiny, tiny contribution to the discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61408/why-isnt-xsl-shown-as-a-tag-synonym-for-xslt-on-the-info-tab-when-it-appears-i)). I have no memory of, nor can I find any reference to, any involvement in a merge of `xsltprocessor` - if you have evidence of any wrong-doing on my part, I suggest you post another discussion and/or contact the team.

Comment: Interestingly, @Dimitre, your stance at the time was admirable: you wrote, "Let's avoid all the etimological, philosophical and historical aspects and just be practical." I'm saddened to observe that you've abandoned practicality in this instance.

Comment: Regarding your next five examples: first is about using xpath in scala. Next is about an error encountered using glassfish. Next is about using xpath with selenium. Next is about tsql, and final is about Sitecore's xpath-like query language. **NONE OF THESE ARE RELATED**, except for a (in some instances very tangential) connection to xpath. They aren't *about* xpath engines. They're about software that is or contains *an xpath engine*, or something like one. That last one wasn't about xpath and wasn't originally tagged as such. And adding [not-xpath] because your answer got down-voted? Ugh.

Comment: @Alejandro, I encourage you to find other examples of suitable questions.  As @Shog9 has pointed out, none of the examples you have provided seem to have any coherent relationship to *xpath engines in general*, thus make poor examples of what would go in an "engines" tag, while *all but the last* have a direct link to the "xpath" tag itself, even if xpath isn't their *central* focus.  If these are your best examples, then I don't think you're going to find much support here.  There just doesn't seem to be a compelling reason to have *catch all* tags for things that aren't *100%* xpath/xquery.

Comment: @Alejandro: why tag them in the first place? They are at least *tangentially* related to xpath, which your tag appeared to recognize: your mistake was in trying to hold them at arm's length. Seeing that [not-xpath] tag in there was a revelation to me: this isn't really about categorizing the tags themselves at all, *now is it* - it's you and Dimitre trying to establish some arbitrarily-defined xpath-purgatory for questions that aren't "pure" enough. That's missing the entire point of the tag system. Either a question has some connection to xpath (tag it) or it doesn't (don't).

Comment: @Alejandro, the argument is that the engines tag adds **zero additional categorical value** to those questions. Those questions **don't seem to have anything else in common**, except the very tenuous relationship of discussing *something* about *someone's* implementation of xpath. The topic isn't coherent or cohesive. Also, all but the last question **are** related to xpath as a *topic*, even though xpath isn't the *main* topic of the questions. If these are the best examples of things in the engines tag, then the engines tag is unnecessary because it **doesn't help categorize the question!**

Comment: I'd also like to clarify the phrase **categorical value**. When I say that, I mean "this tag helps *question askers* find information." Tags aren't just for power users, they're for people asking questions. They're a tool used by *both* sides to help group related questions together. The xpath tag has an obvious categorical value. Questions in it are expected to be about xpath, or be related to xpath. Questions in the engines tag *aren't related to each other*, except *through xpath itself*. (continued)

Comment: The tag adds zero value to *question askers* searching for help, because it has no concrete meaning! You've just been using it as a place to stash questions where xpath isn't the *sole* focus of the question. @Shog9 is right on the money here. The engines tags are misuses of the SO categorization system, and should not exist. Questions can belong in a tag if they are *even tangentially related* to the tag itself. It's *perfectly fine* for any of those example questions to be tagged xpath (except the last one, probably), because the questions *are* related to xpath.

Comment: @Alejandro, I severely disagree with that. Did you know that you can *search for multiple sets of tags at once*? For example, [here are all questions tagged scala+xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala+xpath). All four of those questions *seem* relevant to both tags. It looks like two of those four are about *library use*, which implies that you'd want to engine-ize them. Doing so would *make the questions harder to find*, even though they aren't 100% related to xpath. This isn't about tag purity, it's about making questions findable.

Comment: Alejandro: The merge already happened. At this point, I'm more interested in questions like your last one, which aren't really xpath questions *at all* - those need to just have the tag removed. I'll be going through more of these as I have time, but I'd like to encourage you to do likewise, keeping in mind @Charles's point that users looking for questions on using xpath with scala are probably going to search for "xpath scala" and not "scala *something else that's not xpath*"

Comment: @Dimitre I think you'd see more people willing to work *with* you on this if you'd stop insulting them at every turn.

Comment: @Dimitre I'm not just talking about @Shog9. In general, you've been pretty abrasive to anyone who didn't see things your way. I don't think anybody reading this question cares about your past interactions with other users, nor should we. We're just here to try and help you resolve this particular problem without getting insulted in the process.

Comment: @Dimitre: again, if you've *any* legitimate complaint against me, you do yourself and the site a disservice by failing to report it. And if you don't... Well, you haven't exactly helped poor Alejandro by using his question as a platform for your nonsense.

Comment: @Alejandro, based on your edit, I could see the creation of a new tag, `xpath-implementation-dependent` that could be added to questions in the `xpath` tag when it discusses an implementation-specific issue -- and *only* when it's implementation-specific.  The **core issue** is that such a descriptive tag should be **added** to the question instead of *replacing* the `xpath` tag. *Even implementation-specific questions about xpath are still questions about xpath!*  The purpose of the tag system is to help people categorize questions, not to obtain semantic correctness.

Comment: Regarding the last edit: you didn't use the tag for questions regarding the XPath standard. In fact, you did *the exact opposite* - you used it for questions that concerned *specific implementations* of that standard. If you want to tag *questions on the xpath standard* with [xpath-standard] (or better yet, just [standards]), go for it - it's a pretty good bet that anyone implementing a new xpath engine will be able to understand and use such a thing. But - and I cannot stress this enough - *even then* you should think twice before *removing* the [xpath] tag.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to repeat this once more, since it hasn't sunken in yet: **it is not appropriate to systematically remove a language tag from questions regarding that language simply because answers may not apply to *all* implementations of that language.** This is an overtly hostile action, as it reduces the chances that future readers will find it. These readers may have *no idea* what details of the problem are specific to their implementation, much less the name of the arbitrary tag you've used to replace the *name* of their language. This is very bad. Don't do this.

Comment: The drama continues. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582993/xsl-transformation-cuts-space-between-two-xslvalue-of-selects) I specifically restored the xslt tag, as my (accepted) answer required debugging XSLT code. For some reason Dimitre keeps changing the tag to `xsltprocessor` instead. WHY?? It's not the first time I've seen this kind of vandalism either (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4822883/revisions). I eventually just got sick of fixing it and gave up.

Answer (score -2):

The truth is that many questions are asked about particular
implementations of XPath, and these questions have almost nothing
significantly related to XPath. Merging them together with the true
XPath questions makes finding/answering the true questions difficult
and decreases the overal value of SO for any user that has submitted
an XPath question. I would even start tagging some questions as
"screenscraping".

The situation with "xquery" and "xqueryengines" is the same.

I happen to be the only SO user so far with gold badge in XPath (and
also have gold badges in XSLT and XML). I also happen to be the leader
of the XQuery tag. My competency in these areas as contrasted to that
of the anonymous moderator should be well established and beyond
doubt.

I am officially asking SO to revert this unfortunate and  ignorant
action and to seriously re-consider giving the right to moderaters
from now on to merge tags. The practice of doing this based on
agreement with the tag leaders is the only reasonable solution that
will prevent such problems form occuring repeatedly.

At least these two things have to be done:

1. Reverse the stupid act by an
   anonymous moderator that destroyed
   useful tags without ever asking the
   tag users.
2. The SO administration should only
   allow tag merging after
   investigating the opinion of the
   respective tag users (and especially
   the tag leaders) and if the feedback
   received is significantly positive.
   Moderators should not generally be
   given the right to merge tags
   without following this process.

---

Yes @Alejandro. The vandalism continues.

People, who may not have even a vague notion of XPath and XQuery take decisions to merge tags to "xpath and "xquery", without ever asking the users of these tags.

To me this is similar to burning books in the past dark ages. Yes, burning, because this act is probably not fully reversible.

For your information, there are users who hold the gold badge in XPath, XSLT and XML. Michael Kay. who is the editor of the W3C Working Group on XSLT, developer of the Saxon XSLT and XQuery processors and author of the best books on XSLT and XPath is a SO user. Why don't you at least ask (or better leave to the) competent users in taking such crucial decisions? Because you are so wise? Let your acts speak for themselves.

Comment: Can you explain to us plebes exactly what the functional difference is between the `xpath` tag and the `xpathengines` tag? And then the difference between the `xquery` tag and the `xqueryengines` tag?  The second tags in those pairs simply seem like *unnecessary* specificity -- shouldn't the engine be entirely inconsequential, given that they're all (likely to be properly) implementing a specification? Someone recreated one of the two engine tags today, and I found myself editing it out because the question was about an actual query and didn't mention the engine being used in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, if your practice with XPath and XQuery isn't significant, then you may think so. The same as the people who were allowed to do things they don't understand. Please, read my answer again -- I put there some more information -- for people that don't understand.

Comment: @Dimitre: I appreciate your opinion with which I agree.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I am sure that you and any person that understands the subjectmatter of XPath and XQuery would agree. The problem here is that *ignorance and power combined always lead to destruction*. Nothing new on Earth.

Comment: @Dimitre You can also edit your posts, so deleting and reposting to add new information isn't needed.

Comment: As @Anna notes, you can and *should* edit your answer to add additional information. Re-posting to remove comments or votes you don't like is abusive. Stop it. I've restored your original answer, added your edit, and deleted your re-post: please stick to making a good argument and leave the silly games to users who *haven't* been using this system long enough to garner gold tag badges...

Comment: @Dimitre, could you explain how the *catch-all* `x.+engines` tags are a superior solution than marking questions with the appropriate `xpath`/`xquery` tag *and* a tag for the *specific* engine implementation(s) being asked about?  Or, put another way, is there enough *question volume* about engine implementations *in general*, excluding questions either comparing 2+ engines or about the behavior of a specific engine?  I easily see the use case for engine-specific tags, but I'm just having a really hard time understanding the *need* for another catch-all tag.  I believe *specificity* wins here.

Comment: @Charles: There were **230** questions tagged in such way. I don't think is good to ask @Dimitre for justification **now after what it seems to be a policy change**.

Comment: Agree completely with @Charles' latest comment, +1 on that. -1 on this answer for the tone (and also it not being an actual answer).  The mods aren't out to get you and your precious tag, they were trying to clean up what looked like an unnecessary tag.  I recommend you outline what you believe is appropriate material for those two tags that would *not* be covered better by a different set of tags.

Comment: @Shog9: In the past you were also involved in similar stupid merge, which was later restored (partially) by the SO administration. Now I know who did this. No doubt...

Comment: @Dimitre: If you're talking about the XSLT-XSL thing, I wasn't involved, apart from answering your question about the UI. And you argued *for* that merge... Trust and believe, I had nothing to do with this one, apart from stepping in twice to clean up the mess you've made of your answers here. I'm locking this answer - if you want to post yet another one, I suggest you answer the questions being asked here rather than abusing your privileges to silence other users.